# Does localforage.clear() clear all the data in this table in this database?

Tags: javascript, localforage

For example, my localForage is using IndexedDB for data access, and I am using the default configuration or I have modified the name and storeName of my driver. The function localforage.clear() is the corresponding table of the corresponding database in the configuration. Do you want to perform an empty operation? or the entire database.

The official docs are vague about this.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you asking how localForage implements the `clear()` operation?

Comment: It's open source, you can read the code.